# How do I clean up Scala generated HTML (issue due to IE9 table bug)?

Tags: playframework-2.0

There appears to be a significant table parsing bug in IE9 which my application needs to support.  ([Internet Explorer 9 not rendering table cells properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805956/internet-explorer-9-not-rendering-table-cells-properly) & http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/28d78780-c95c-4c35-9695-237ebb912d90/) The issue arises when there is extra whitespace in the table markup.

I'm using Scala style for-each loops in my template to generate the table which is introducing a lot of whitespace to the generated HTML.  None of the CSS or HTML meta tags that I've seen are working.  One option I haven't tried yet due to the amount of re-work involved is to generate the HTML dynamically with AJAX and clean it up with regex before displaying it.  I'm hoping to find a simpler solution.  Has anyone else come across this issue and if so, what did you do to fix it?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154671/is-it-possible-to-prettify-scala-templates-using-play-framework-2/14212307

Comment: @AdrienBe Thanks.  biesior also noted this other topic and pointed me to it in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest solution that doesn't require any additional steps is writing condensed code in your view, like:

```
@for(item <- items){<tr><td>@item.name</td></tr>}
```

Optionally you can even write a static method that will trim the value inside very precisely:

```
@for(item <- items){utils.Trimmer.addTableRow(item.name)}
```

Using string functions in the class you'll get much better control over spaces and other special chars, than just using bare views.

Finally you can use Google's [htmlcompressor](https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/) to compress and minify whole site, there's is an option `remove-intertag-spaces` however in this case you'll need to put some hard space to keep the space where required ie, `<td>&nbsp;</td>`

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14212307/1066240) to check how to implement it quite easy in Play 2.x

Comment: Thanks for the possible solutions.  I finally got around to trying a few things.  Unfortunately, simply condensing the code didn't seem to work (not to mention make things quite unmanageable due to nested loops and/or a multitude of custom attributes).  I did find that simply moving all the embedded Scala to the leftmost position (shown as the initial attempt at beautifying [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154671/is-it-possible-to-prettify-scala-templates-using-play-framework-2/14212307#14212307) worked.  It's ugly, but it's an initial fix.  I'll try html compression soon & report.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay, but...HTML Compression did the trick!  I followed the solution of overriding the Controller methods with a custom class to interface with Google's compressor found in the link you passed along.  Many thanks!